# Recursion in C with an array inside and an index

Tags: c, recursion, global-variables

I am trying to do a function that receives the root of a supposed BST and I want to know if the tree in question is a BST.

Problem is that, I am traveling the tree with recursion and what I'm trying to do is, put inside an array all the values of the tree. I searched for how to put a BST into an array (AddtoArray), but the answers I've found on stackoverflow and other websites didn't solve my problem. (I got seg fault).

Here's what I got so far:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct node{
        int key;
        struct node *left, *right;
    };

    struct node *newNode(int item){
        struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->key = item;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key){
        if(node == NULL) return newNode(key);

        if(key < node->key)
            node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
        else if(key >= node->key)
            node->right = insert(node->right, key);

        return node;
    }

    void check(struct node *root, int *array, int i){
        if(root != NULL){
            check(root->left, array, i);
            array[i++] = root->key;
            //I tried to put i++, ++i in every place of this function (trying table test) and I realized it was too difficult to realize what to do here, I've found some functions returning an integer, the "i" in question, but they didn't work out for me.
            check(root->right, array, i);
        }
    }

    int main(){

        int *array;
        int array_length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
        int i = 0;


        array = (int*)malloc(array_length*sizeof(int));

        struct node *root = NULL;
        root = insert(root, 50);
        insert(root, 30);
        insert(root, 20);
        insert(root, 40);
        insert(root, 70);
        insert(root, 60);
        insert(root, 20);

        check(root, array, i);

        printf("PRINTING ARRAY TO SEE IF THE BST IS IN ARRAY:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
            printf("VALUE: %d ", array[i]);
        }

        free(array);
        return 0;
    }
```

I'd like to solve this problem WITHOUT using global variables. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your `check`-code and its usage (did not analyse the other functions):

First, your `malloc` does not work as intended, because `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` will always give the same (small) value, probably `1` or `2`, regardless of the size of your BST.

So you'd rather introduce a function getting the number of nodes and use this as the length for your array:

```
    int array_length = getNrOfNodes(root); // function to be coded
    int *array = malloc(array_length*sizeof(int));
```

Second, you pass an integral value `i` by value to a recursive function. As it is passed by value, any `i++` will take effect only for the respective function call instance, but will not influence the other ones  on the call stack. So it is very likely that the keys of the complete left part of your tree (the one before `i` is altered), will be written to `array[0]`.

I'd suggest to share the array index among the function instances on the call stack. This can be achieved by passing a pointer to some `i` rather than passing `i`-s value around. And I'd introduce an internal version that does the work, because the user of the function needs not to be aware of the helper variable `i`:

```
void writeToArray_internal(struct node *root, int *array, int *i){
    if(root != NULL){
        writeToArray_internal(root->left, array, i);
        array[*i] = root->key;
        (*i)++;
        writeToArray_internal(root->right, array, i);
    }

}
void writeToArray(struct node *root, int *array) {
    int i=0;
    writeToArray_internal(root, array, &i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line here

```
int array_length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

is wrong. This only works with pure arrays, because `sizeof` returns the amount
of bytes of the expression/variable. Your variable `array` is a pointer, so
`sizeof array` returns you the size of a pointer and it doesn't matter where the
pointer is pointer, you always will get the same size.

Besides trying to get the number of elements of the "array" before knowing how
many nodes you have, makes no sense, because the number of elements that you need in `array` depend on the number of nodes, so
you've got write a function that returns you the number of nodes and **then**
you can allocate space for `array`.

Also note that your `check` function is not correct either. The variable `i` is
local to every call of `check` so you are going to overwrite values of the
array, because the `i++` of the `n`-th iteration only affects the `i` of the
`n`-the iteration, the `n-1`-th iteration does not see that change and thus
overwrites the value of the `n`-th iteration.

You'll need to pass `i` as a pointer as well:

```
void check(struct node *root, int *array, size_t *i, size_t maxlen) {
    if(root != NULL){
        check(root->left, array, i, maxlen);
        if(*i < maxlen)  // checking that you don't step out of bounds
            array[(*i)++] = root->key;
        check(root->right, array, i, maxlen);
    }
}
```

and the you call it like this:

```
size_t i  = 0;
size_t nodes_number = get_number_of_nodes(root); // you have to write this function

int *array = malloc(nodes_number * sizeof *array);

if(array == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // do not continue
}

check(root, array, &i, nodes_number);
```

Comment: Yes Pablo, I realized before by table test that when I arrived to the leaf nodes, the variable i was fine, but as I was going up on the tree, the values of i wasn't following up the increment I was doing, of course, because it's recursive, so back on the stack, the values were smaller than the actual that I wanted.
About the int array_length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);, I forgot that I change my array[20] to *array, so ye, it doesn't make sense.
I've built the get_number_of_nodes and did what you said and it solved my problem, thanks a lot! Btw, smart solution you made on check funct.

Comment: Nice to hear (or read) that you've solved your problem with my help. If you find that my answer helpful, then you can always upvote or accept the answer.